# How to undo a delete operation in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transaction-log

Our Test DB is suddenly missing rows. We want them back.

Is there a way to sift through everything that has happened to the database today? Each SQL statement? I presume this kind of stuff is in the transaction log, but am not sure how to view it.

Is there a way to undo delete operations?

BTW: Yes, we do have a backup, but would prefer to find the cause of the deletion as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some of [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com)'s tools, but it costs. Take a look at [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm).

Otherwise, I'd be tempted to do a restore.

Comment: Yeah, we did just do a restore (to local db) and tried to figure out from there, patching to test db.

Answer (score 2):

*[late answer but hopefully useful]*

There is a way to recover deleted rows using transaction log but only if you use 3rd party tools and only of your database is in full recovery mode.

Dell (formerly Quest) has [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) and ApexSQL has [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) and [ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) that can also read t-log and recover data. Unfortunately Log Rescue from Red Gate can only read logs on SQL Server 2000.

There is also a way to read t-log using undocumented dbcc log command. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008).

Considering you already have database backups you can restore these in separate database and then use one of many data comparison tools that exist on the market to insert missing data into production database. Of course this can only recover data delete prior to creating a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You need a third-party tool to do this.  The tool has to be able to go into the transaction logs and view the log entries so you can see what happened.  I haven't used any of these tools, but I'd try Red Gate's SQL Log Rescue for starters.  Give it a try:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'd give ChronicDB a try which has a free version rather than pay for Red Gate

http://chronicdb.com/blogs/undelete_from_whoops

Answer (score -1):

You can undo a transaction by using `Rollback` command in SQL Server. But, you need to know the transaction can be rolledback if the transaction were performed within `Begin` transaction.

Comment: It's clear the user is not in the midst of a transaction, so this answer doesn't apply at all.