# How can I rollback an UPDATE query in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update, rollback

How can I rollback an UPDATE query in SQL server 2005?

I need to do this in SQL, not through code.

Comment: what do you mean with update? can you get a little further on this question?

Comment: i have updated an table which was my terrible mistake..instead of updting single row..with my carelessness have updated all rows...how do i roll back this....please help.....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
begin transaction

// execute SQL code here

rollback transaction
```

If you've already executed the query and want to roll it back, unfortunately your only real option is to restore a database backup. If you're using Full backups, then you should be able to restore the database to a specific point in time.

Comment: what do you mean by Full Backups, should i  backup database daily , i am new to this ?

Answer (score 29):

You need this tool and you can find the transaction and reverse it.

[ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp?gclid=COWEvOex3JkCFQMQswod4RgXXA)

Comment: "Ooops - wish you can rollback that Update statement without a where clause!?  ApexSQL Log has the ability to ROLLBACK transactions for SQL Server databases." Great line!

Comment: that toll seems great but it cost 2000$

Answer (score 6):

You can use **implicit transactions** for this

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

update Staff set staff_Name='jas' where staff_id=7

ROLLBACK
```

As you request-- You can SET this setting ( `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`) from a stored procedure by setting that stored procedure as the start up procedure.

But `SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTION ON` command is connection specific. So any connection other than the one which running the start up stored procedure will not benefit from the setting you set.

Answer (score 5):

You can rollback the statements you've executed within a transaction.
Instead of commiting the transaction, rollback the transaction.

If you have updated something and want to rollback those updates, and you haven't done this inside a (not-yet-commited) transaction, then I think it's though luck ...

(Manually repair, or, restore backups)

Answer (score 1):

Once an update is committed you can't rollback just the single update. Your best bet is to roll back to a previous backup of the database.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you have specified, your best chance of recovery is through a database backup. I don't think you're going to be able to rollback any of those changes you pushed through since you were apparently not using transactions at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to do:

header code...

```
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection

Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command Set

objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo ERRORHAND
```

Working code...

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = ConnStr

objMyConn.Open
```

code....

'Copy Data FROM Excel'

```
objMyConn.BeginTrans <-- define transactions to possible be rolled back 

For NewRows = 2 To Rows

objMyRecordset.AddNew 

For NewColumns = 0 To Columns - 1

objMyRecordset.Fields(NewColumns).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(NewRows, NewColumns + 1)

Next NewColumns objMyRecordset.Update Next NewRows

objMyConn.CommitTrans <- if success, commit them to DB

objMyConn.Close
```

ERRORHAND:

```
Success = False 

objMyConn.RollbackTrans <-- here we roll back if error encountered somewhere

LogMessage = "ERROR writing database: " & Err.Description
```

...

Answer (score 0):

As already stated there is nothing you can do except restore from a backup. At least now you will have learned to always wrap statements in a transaction to see what happens before you decide to commit. Also, if you don't have a backup of your database this will also teach you to make regular backups of your database.

While we haven't been much help for your imediate problem...hopefully these answers will ensure you don't run into this problem again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

in this example we run 2 line insert into query and if all of them true it run but if not no run anything and ROLLBACK

```
DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
BEGIN TRY 
 insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl1] (fld1) values('1') ;
    set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
 insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl2] (fld1) values('2') ;
    set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 

IF @rowcount =  2
  COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END CATCH
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
ROLLBACK WORK;
```

It usually works