# Disable Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Oracle has SQL commands that one can issue so that a transaction does not get logged. Is there something similar for SQL Server 2008?

My scenario: We need Tx logs on servers (Dev, QA, Prod), but maybe we can do without them on developer machines.

Comment: have you tried using views for your calculated data?

Comment: Sorry to hijack your question, but how to disable transaction logging in oracle for a particualr procedure/query? Thank you!

Comment: @Kaushik you're better off asking this as it's own question.

Comment: "*so that a transaction does not get logged*" this is not true if you are referring to the `NOLOGGED` option.

Comment: @RajMore Did you learn anything more on this topic? In our case we are doing bulk loading and it was surprising to see so much data being shoveled to the disk by the SIMPLE mode. Now I understand why but I wonder how much performance might increase if the transaction logging could be eliminated.

Comment: Recovery Models https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can't do without transaction logs in SQL Server, under any circumstances.  The engine simply won't function.

You CAN set your recovery model to SIMPLE on your dev machines - that will prevent transaction log bloating when tran log backups aren't done.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

Comment: Just a BIG heads up: This answer is 100% technically correct. But it's solely something you'd want to use on your DEVELOPER machines or when you do NOT care about being able to backup your data. See 
http://www.sqlservervideos.com/video/logging-essentials/ and
http://www.sqlservervideos.com/video/shrinking-log-files/ for more info and background.

Comment: Or for databases on RDS (or equivalent services) where the backup strategy uses snapshots rather than transaction logs.

Comment: or the db is built from another source e.g. event sourcing so there are no transactions and no need for logging

Comment: Or it's a database used for batch ETL/ELT loads for data warehouse and/or analytical environments, where you always have the raw data available to reload and you don't rely on logs for recovery.

Answer (score 51):

There is a third recovery mode not mentioned above. The recovery mode ultimately determines how large the LDF files become and how ofter they are written to. In cases where you are going to be doing any type of bulk inserts, you should set the DB to be in "BULK/LOGGED". This makes bulk inserts move speedily along and can be changed on the fly.

To do so,

```
USE master ;
ALTER DATABASE model SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED ;
```

To change it back:

```
USE master ;
ALTER DATABASE model SET RECOVERY FULL ;
```

In the spirit of adding to the conversation about why someone would not want an LDF, I add this: We do multi-dimensional modelling. Essentially we use the DB as a large store of variables that are processed in bulk using external programs. We do not EVER require rollbacks. If we could get a performance boost by turning of ALL logging, we'd take it in a heart beat.

Comment: Thanks for this. We use the DB in exactly the same way. We couldn't care less about being able to roll back. Pure performance is all we are after

Comment: For this scenario you might consider a different database like Mongo (allows disabling logs) or in memory (redis and others)

Answer (score 47):

SQL Server requires a transaction log in order to function.

That said there are two modes of operation for the transaction log:

- Simple
- Full

In **Full** mode the transaction log keeps growing until you back up the database. In **Simple** mode: space in the transaction log is 'recycled' every *Checkpoint*.

Very few people have a need to run their databases in the **Full** recovery model. The only point in using the Full model is if you want to backup the database multiple times per day, and backing up the whole database takes too long - so you just backup the transaction log.

The transaction log keeps growing all day, and you keep backing just it up. That night you do your full backup, and SQL Server then *truncates* the transaction log, begins to reuse the space allocated in the transaction log file.

If you only ever do **full database backups**, you don't want the Full recovery mode.

Comment: This is bit wrong: you need to backup the *log* to (hopefully) stop the transaction log growing. Of course, if you have an open transaction or a huge transaction, then the log will grow because the internal log file allocations (VLFs) cannot be reused or you need more. That's a quick overview BTW, not chapter and verse

Comment: @gbn You don't backup the log to stop the log from growing. i mean you *do*, but that's not the *point* of the feature. Microsoft didn't create a transaction log in order to play the game *"consume your entire hard drive because you forgot to backup the log"*. The *reason* the log keeps growing (and then requires backing up to stop it from growing), is so that you can backup *just* the log.

Answer (score 2):

What's your problem with Tx logs? They grow? Then just set truncate on checkpoint option.

From Microsoft documentation:

> In SQL Server 2000 or in SQL Server
>   2005, the "Simple" recovery model is
>   equivalent to "truncate log on
>   checkpoint" in earlier versions of SQL
>   Server. If the transaction log is
>   truncated every time a checkpoint is
>   performed on the server, this prevents
>   you from using the log for database
>   recovery. You can only use full
>   database backups to restore your data.
>   Backups of the transaction log are
>   disabled when the "Simple" recovery
>   model is used.

Comment: Well, space issues - some dev's have older machines and we can do without. More to the point, I am curious if this is at all possible!

I was under the impression that the "Truncate Log on Checkpoint" option was only set using the Simple recovery mode in SQL 2008.  Is there another way?

Comment: @Tapori, they're the same thing. They renamed it in 2000.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for dev machines in order to save space then just go with simple recovery mode and you’ll be doing fine.

On production machines though I’d strongly recommend that you keep the databases in full recovery mode. This will ensure you can do point in time recovery if needed.

Also – having databases in full recovery mode can help you to undo accidental updates and deletes by reading transaction log.  See below or more details.

[How can I rollback an UPDATE query in SQL server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721471/how-can-i-rollback-an-update-query-in-sql-server-2005)

[Read the log file (*.LDF) in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054/read-the-log-file-ldf-in-sql-server-2008)

If space is an issue on production machines then just create frequent transaction log backups.