# SQL SERVER 2008 Logging log

Tags: sql-server-2008

in SQL Server 2008 is there any way to disable transaction log or clear log file?

When I execute one query in my project (very large in terms of transaction) a that time this log file's size will goring to increase (20 to 30 GB).

now i want to disable it any other option for it

Answer (score 1):

you can use this T-SQL To clear Log file.

```
BACKUP log [CustomerServiceSystem] with truncate_only
go
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ([CustomerServiceSystem], 10, TRUNCATEONLY)
go
```

and for Disable Log you can use this

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996403/disable-transaction-log)