# Insert Into From Select Performance SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-insert

I created a query in which I insert to a empty table the result of a select from other table.

This **select** itself takes **~20 minutes** (30 M Rows, 120 Columns and "Where" conditions, and it's fine), but the **insert** into takes **~1 hour**.

Do you have any suggestions of how to improve it?

What I've done is as in the below example.

```
Insert Into tableA
Select *
From TableB
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop all the indexes on `TableA` , then insert again :

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Indexes are known to slow down insert statements .

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? MySQL or SQL-Server ? @Ric_R

Comment: SQL Server. Thanks

Comment: Read here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99367/insert-into-table-select-from-table-vs-bulk-insert @Ric_R

Answer (score 0):

Beneath the already mentioned indexes you could check if  TableA  has constraints defined (primary key, foreign key, etc.) since constraints are often implemented by indexes.

Furthermore you could check if there are triggers on TableA. 
Another test would be to export/unload TableB to a file e.g. TableB.txt and then import/load the file TableB.txt into TableA. (Sorry I don't know the syntax for SQL Server).

Another item to check may be the transaction log. Probably it is possible to change logging to BULK_LOGGED see:
[Disable Transaction Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996403/disable-transaction-log)

Comment: Constraints and triggers should not be fired while doing a `SELECT`. Constraints and triggers will run only on DML events (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to drop table and do these will be faster
`Select * INTO TableB from tableA`
Also mentioned
[here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/19/which-is-faster-insert-into-select-or-select-into-interview-question-of-the-week-187/)