# how to get the modified column name in tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if we want to get the changes happened in database we will get through  sys.objects or sys.tables .but  we are only getting it table name . But how to get by table name and what the column added to that table or what column has been modified (datatype or constraint) .

for example if i added employee table column called deptid it should be shown in changes in geiven date

```
tablename,modified or added column
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for Change Tracking.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no supported way to do this though system views.

What you can do is to setup [DDL audit triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the database objects you want to monitor or to try and read transaction log if database was in full recovery mode.

Audit triggers will only be helpful if you want to start auditing now while reading transcation log might give you some historical data about the changes made in the database.

[Read the log file (*.LDF) in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054/read-the-log-file-ldf-in-sql-server-2008)

[How to view transaction logs in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008)