# can i uncommit after commiting the transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have updated 100 rows on one column which have different values in it e.g. 3,5,2,1,4,5 etc but i have wrongly updated all with value 9 and also committed it. is there any way that i can revert the previous values to that column?
iam using sql server r2

Comment: No, unless you log every modification. You can rollback before commiting, but once commited, values are overwritten. Use backups.

Comment: Also if that column contain value of calculated field then also you can re-update those columns and rows with appropriate query .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn’t support this  but in some cases it is possible to recover data by reading transaction log. This works if database was in full recovery mode and 3rd party tools like ApexSQL Log or Log Rescue are needed. There is also a way to read t-log using DBCC LOG command but it too difficult.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054/read-the-log-file-ldf-in-sql-server-2008)