# Update query cancelled by user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, where-clause

I have a table that has millions of rows.

Accidentally I wrote an update query over a table without where clause and clicked execute.

It started executing. After  two seconds I realized the query is wrong and I clicked '`Stop`' button in `Sql Server Management Studio`. The query execution was stopped, this all happened within 7 seconds.

Now I am curious to know if there are any rows affected. If any which are they?
How to find it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rollback an UPDATE query in SQL server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721471/how-can-i-rollback-an-update-query-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I dont think so njk. I dont want to rollback, I want to know number of rows affected. Thanks

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni You have no rollback to do cause no commit was made. SQL server does the commit at the end of the statement but you canceled. So no row affected

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A single update statement will not update some rows. It's all rows or none

This is the [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) in the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties which SQL server respects well.

> Atomicity requires that each transaction is "all or nothing": if one part of the transaction fails, the entire transaction fails, and the database state is left unchanged. An atomic system must guarantee atomicity in each and every situation, including power failures, errors, and crashes.

Then the commit is at the end of the statement, so when you cancel there's no commit

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The question is "Now I am curious to know if there any rows affected if any which are they". There's not so

Comment: So as per my understanding no rows were changed right? Thanks a lot. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: That's a statement. The question is, "Ho to find it."

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni I would recommend you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/721511/679449) answer to help with your issue.

Comment: @njk there's no rollback to do. No commit was made