# cancel an sql server query from SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I was running an update  sql server query.Unfortunately I realized that I miss a condition so I quickly canceled manually the query with the red (stop) button in sql server management studio. I want to know if a rollback is done on the updated data or not. It was a simple sql server query without begin transaction and commit or rollback clause.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13531879/22194

Answer (score 4):

Yes it should be rolled back. AFAIK, `UPDATE`/`INSERT` runs on implicit transaction block; i.e, they will either complete or not (atomic operation).

With that in mind, the moment you have clicked the red stop button; it must have rolled back the update operation transaction.

You can verify that, by issuing a `select` query against the same table and see if the data have been updated or not.