# How to roll back delete operation sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an input page in my C# application whereby my boss can enter sales info.

This page also has a clear button, which clears the contents of the table in the database. This clear button was convenient for testing, however now in hindsight a mistake.

All the records in the table have been deleted. There are no backups either.

Long shot, but is there any way of recovering this data using only SQL Server 2008?

Comment: You have backups, right? Right?

Comment: `however now in hindsight a mistake` .... oh!

Comment: You could jump in your time machine and either turn on database backups, or better yet get rid of the Clear button that obviously didn't belong in your deployed app.

Comment: it is a DBA in your company?? http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2010/07/08/thing-you-would-never-hear-a-dba-say.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the transaction logs, there are some tools, but these will cost some ...

See
[How to undo a delete operation in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201524/how-to-undo-a-delete-operation-in-sql-server-2005)

and
https://web.archive.org/web/20080215075500/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-recover-data-from-sql-server-s-log-files.html

Edit : Looks like Redgate is SQL 2000 only. Which leaves Apex. And if your clear function uses TRUNCATE, you are up the creek.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**( 2008 support)

[SQL Data Compare Professional](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

This version of SQL Data Compare, you can compare a live database with or against backup files and synchronize data and deleted tables with their data contents from the backup file or backup file set to the live database.

Redgate even say this should do the same job, and that is why they have not come with any new version.

Will probably need a backup or transaction log ....

---

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201524/how-to-undo-a-delete-operation-in-sql-server-2005) subject.

Comment: OP wants *>way of recovering this data using only SQL Server 2008*