# recover/restore table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I just deleted the data on a table, msssql database.10 minutes ago. I have no backup.

How can I restore and recover my data?

Delete from account where user_id=9999

I remember taking backup and restore from transaction logs etc..

Anyway I found an article about this issue, and recovering.

Thanks everyone

Comment: What method did you use to delete it?

Comment: What is your recovery model set to? Have you **ever** taken a backup?

Comment: If that was on prod, time to update your resume.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a Delorean and enough road to get it up to 88 mph, you need a backup to restore from or a third party tool.

[See this question/answer on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201524/how-to-undo-a-delete-operation-in-sql-server-2005)

[Another related question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499826/how-to-roll-back-delete-operation-sql-server)

Comment: The Redgate tool is SQL Server 2000 only. Apex and Quest do log readers for later versions.