# Undo "Update" statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-update, undo, recovery

I'm using SQL Server 2005 with `FULL` recovery model. I accidentally executed the `UPDATE` statement without specify the condition using `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Column1 = 'All'
```

Now all `Column1` values are set to `'All'`. And I need to undo the `column1` values to the previous values.

Any idea?

ps:: I executed the `UPDATE` on 27-02-2016 and I have backup file that is on 21-02-2016.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have not yet committed: `rollback;`

Comment: too bad. it's committed. :(

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201554/243373) on the question [How to undo a delete operation in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201524/243373). If you can't use tools, look at a recent backup, restore it to a database with a different name, and reconstruct the column by creating a T-SQL update statement linking tables in the two databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't commit it, you can do Rollback